# Populist badge takes up multiple lines on several sites

Tags: bug, status-completed

On many SE sites, the Populist badge appears broken. It takes up two lines, instead of one, and that doesn't look very nice.

- [UX](https://ux.stackexchange.com/badges/49/populist)
- [Home Improvement](https://diy.stackexchange.com/badges/39/populist)
- [EL&U](https://english.stackexchange.com/badges/49/populist)
- [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/badges/39/populist)
- [GIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/badges/39/populist)

The above sites were picked at random (other than EL&U, where I first noticed it, and posted about it [here,](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2301/multi-line-populist-badge) which elicited no actual action. Is it too trivial for the SE team to care, or will it be fixed, since it occurs on so many sites? I believe that it also happens on Apple and Android. Drupal has a [different problem,](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/badges/39/populist) as the text is only half there.

Please note that since this is happening on multiple websites, I chose to do up a general post here because it will attract more attention, but mostly because it would be too time-consuming to go to each individual website's Meta and post there.

I am using Safari 5.1 on Mac OS X 10.7.2. The responses to my post on Meta - EL&U would suggest that most people can see this bug. For those of you that can't, here it is:
[image]

Comment: Yeap, I see it, Chrome 16.0.912.7 Win - What's your browser?

Comment: @ZaphodBeeblebrox Oh, right. I'll update my question. Safari 5.1

Comment: Seems to work fine on FF 8.0.1 & 9.0.1 Win

Comment: Hmm, that is interesting.

Comment: Could you add the image from your EL&U meta post, since you have it handy?

Comment: @ZaphodBeeblebrox Sure.

Comment: As a sidenote, you could have flagged your EL&U meta post for moderation attention and ask for it to be migrated here, didn't really had to go through all the trouble of re-writting this. I'd add the image myself, but I don't have edit privileges, so I thought it'd be faster to just ask :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed next build, thanks - the joys of css